# Determine the limit points of the set and whether the set is open/closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I am asked the following:

Given the set $S=\{(-1)^n+\frac{2}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

1. What are the limit points?
2. Is the set open? Closed?
3. Does the set contain any isolated points?
4. Find the closure of the set.

---

For 1, I have determined the limit points to be $\{1,-1\}$, since $S:=\{(-1)^{2k}+\frac{2}{2k}|k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup \{(-1)^{2k+1}+\frac{2}{2k+1}|k\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
Computing the limits of the sequence contained in S yield $1$ and $-1$, respectively.

For 2, I have roughly worked out that the set is neither open nor closed. 
I'm having difficulty on justifying this conclusion.

If $n=1$, then $1\in S$. However, I'm unsure how to state that $-1\not\in S$.

For 3, the only example I'm familiar with w/r/t isolated points is $A=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, in which each element of the set is an isolated point. However, I'm having difficulty abstracting from this example the necessary details.

Part 4 is contingent on whether or not my limit points are correct, if so, then $\bar{A}=A\cup\{-1\}$.

---

This is homework and I'm just looking to clear up any misunderstandings or mistakes I've made.

Comment: If $n$ is even then $x_n>1$, if $n$ is odd then $x_n>-1$. In both cases $x_n\neq-1$ so $-1\notin S$ as you state.

Comment: Isolated points $x \in A \subseteq \mathbb R$ are those points for which we can find an open set $U_x$ such that $x \in U_x$ and $U_x \cap A = \{ x \}$. So in this case, all points are isolated (just take a small enough interval around any given point).

Answer (score 1):

Your limit points are correct, and the approach of splitting the set into the union of a finite number of disjoint subsets and taking the union of the limit points of those subsets is a valid approach. (You cannot validly do the same trick splitting $S$ into an infinite set of disjoint subsets.)

The set is not open because (for example) the point $\frac32\in S$ has no neighborhood  which is a subset of $S$. And in fact the neighborhood $(\frac{11}{8},\frac{13}{8})$ of $\frac32$ contains no other points in $S$, so $\frac32$ is an isolated point.

Part 4: Your conclusion is correct, as is your set of limit points.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you picked $\frac{3}{2}$? What should my thought process be when I'm looking for isolated points?

Comment: I noticed that the only points in $S \cup (1,2)$ are of the form $1+\frac{1}{2k}$.  I chose the first of those because it is easy to see there is no other value of $1+\frac{1}{2k}$ in the interval $(\frac43 , \frac53)$ which in turn implies that there is certainly no neighborheed of $\frac32$ contained in $S$.